# Is It Possible to Select a MySQL Connection String Based on the Value of a Variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to connect to different databases depending on the value of a variable.

I was thinking of trying something like this:

```
if ($city = 'phoenix') {
   mysql_connect("x", "y", "z") or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("databasename") or die(mysql_error());
}

if ($city = 'losangeles') {
   mysql_connect("a", "b", "c") or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("databasename2") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: -1 because this isn't really a question, but "try this for me". I answered anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As Tomalak said, yes.

Though, consider a switch statement.

```
switch ($city) {
    case 'phoenix':
        //do db
        break;
    case 'losangeles':
        //do db
        break;
    default:
        //do db
}
```

Comment: +1 definitly use this code, checking the database name against a pre-approved whitelist is the **only** way to protect against SQL-injection of a DB name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Yes, it is.

Give it a go!

<sup>(Though watch your syntax for conditionals. `=` is assignment; `==` is comparison.)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Yes, certainly possible.  But it does open up another level of error possibilities and headaches for the person maintaining it.  My company's main app was written this way, and it's a nightmare.  That being said, it is possible to conditionally set the DB.

Or you could just use fully qualified values (use dbname.tablename)